# "Reject" popup is doublified in JavaScript when reviewing suggested edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, javascript

I was in the middle of writing a script to add keyboard shortcuts to /review pages, and I came across something... weird.

Screenshot (click to enlarge):

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, there are *two* `div`s with an ID of `rejection-prototype`! Furthermore, one is hidden (`display: none`) and doesn't seem to do anything, while the second one (which happens to be really hard to get to, since jQuery always selects the first one) is the "real" dialog that actually functions correctly. (Edit: This one does have the `popup` class, which lets you select it easily, but still.)

I get that this is possibly a prototype (wow, who would have guessed?) and not fully finished, but if so, should it really be active on all Stack Exchange sites? Shouldn't it be tested and completed before using it everywhere?

Comment: Also, the realtime tab has `#mainArea` inside `#mainArea` and I don't think it's my fault.

Comment: @JanDvorak - where do you see this? On se.com? What Url?

Comment: @Oded http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime#; but it seems to be fixed now

Comment: OK, I was looking at that page and was wondering if that was the one, as I couldn't repro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what happens when you `.clone()` and insert to the same page without changing the Id.

The "real" popup will be `rejection-popup`.

Fixed in the next build (rev 2014.7.28.1731, meta rev 2014.7.28.2400).